# Issue while rendering multiple sub reports with different header and footer in a main report

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2016, sql-server-data-tools, sql-server-2017

I have around 10 SSRS reports (i.e. 10 .rdl files) and those needs to be exported to one PDF. How can I do this? Do I need to write custom C#.Net code or SSDT 2017 provides any simple feature to export that?

Please note that, all the RDL files has different header and footer, The 1st page has image in it,few pages has both tabular as well as matrix report.

[image: An example I am trying]

As suggested, I have one main report and I'm adding sub-report one after another (just maintain the sequence)

I searched on MSDN, however, it looks like Microsoft does not have such feature till now OR may be I'm missing something? Or any special setting or .Net code needs to be written?

Note: I have two version of SSDT (2016 and 2017)

Comment: I don't think it is possible without lot of custom coding on different platform. This seems like a very unique requirement. Can you explain more why these 10 rdl needs to be exported in same PDF? There may be chances that we can find an alternative design for all the 10 rdl into 1 and then can be exported together in same pdf.

Answer (score 1):

You could just create a master report and then put your 10 reports in that as subreports.

If you reports take a parameters then all the parameters will have to be setup in the master report and then passed to the sub report.

Then, just run the master report and export to PDF...

Comment: Did as suggested. While report review, the individual report header and footer are not appearing. Also, after exporting (the main report) to a single PDF, the individual pages are getting scattered. For example, My 1st page image is getting distributed in 1st page (half image) and in 3rd page (other half image). Similarly, the tables having 4 or 5 columns are coming in separate pages (that is 2 in one page and other 3 in a different page). What am I doing wrong? And, how to fix this?   Please note that, every pages are rendering good individually.